# opencv 2.1 crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, crash

I use visual studio 2010 for opencv. sample codes .c works perfectly but .cpp crash. Do you know what is the problem.

Here is the screen shot of problem. [screenshot](http://twitpic.com/8o3y4w)

Comment: I can barely read the error msg in that picture. Anyway, it's very difficult to locate the source of the problem when you don't have access to the code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are mixing an openCV download built with mingw with your code built with visual studio.

C++ compilers create different library formats for loading code, C compilers are much more similar

Download an openCV build for your compiler or build it yourself

Comment: I dowloaded opencv from it's official website then to make it run on VS-2010 I followed the steps on theirs prompts. And I used cmake for compile. Code is samples code I do not change anything in the code. I dont know mingw.